# Android: how to Parcel complex classes and their subclasses

Tags: android, class, reflection, parcelable

Supose these simple classes:

```
public class Class_A
{
    // no fields
}

public class Class_B extends Class_A
{
    public float field_1;
    public String / int / float / etc...; // dozens of fields
    public int field_N;
}

public class Class_C extends Class_A
{
    public int field_1;
    public String / int / float / etc...; // dozens of fields
    public String field_N;  
}

public class Class_D 
{
    public Class_B class_B;
    public Class_C class_D;
}
```

1) Is it possible to parcel Class_B / Class_C using reflection in Class_A ? How?

2) How to parcel Class_D ?

3) How to "re-mount" Class_D from Intent after passing it to an Activity ?